# Detect if \\ can be used

Tags: line-breaking

How can I detect if I am at a point in the source where I can end a text line, for example, with `\\[5pt]`?

I would like to have something like

```
\ifTEST \\[5pt]\else\vspace*{5pt}\fi
```

but I do not know what "TEST" might be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can test for horizontal mode like so:

```
 \ifhmode \\ \else \vspace*{5pt} \fi
```

although it's often a sign that something else is wrong if you are needing to do this?

Comment: +1 for "it's often a sign that something else is wrong".

Comment: Hmm! Might break if in inner mode.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides it might break at the start of a table cell as well, it depends what the OP needs, as I tried to hint in my answer, it's better to know where you are and not need to ask:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sure:) How about `\ifinner !!!\aftergroup{\vspace*{5pt}}\else ...\\[5pt]\fi`?

Comment: @YiannisLazarides `\ifinner\aftergroup` would still fail if you were in a group within the box, and in LaTeX, you typically are, for color support if nothing else. If you know _exactly_ where you are, you can insert code to get you out of there, but if you know that. you don't need a test:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sure, pointless and error prone approach.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: You didn't say that `\aftergroup{\vspace*{5pt}}` isn't TeX syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the primitive `\vskip`, which breaks your line and enters vertical mode.Best practice is `\vskip 5pt \vskip 0pt` to ensure `\removelastskip`, used in some macros, does not remove your vertical skip.